# How to use function in map TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have defined a function that I want to pass to `.map`:

```
export let disableTabsByRights = (permissions: string[], type: string) => permissions.includes(type);

export let disableTabsByUsers = ();
```

Where `this.tabs` is array:

```
do(fn: Function) {
    this.tabs = this.tabs.map((item) => {
     item.disabled = fn(item.type); 
     return item;
    });
}
```

I want to call outside

```
do(disableTabsByRights(["VIEW"]));
```

Why it does not work for me?

So I want to change easy realizations?

Comment: How doesn't work? What happens and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Seems to work for me at https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-demo-sandbox-poekg

Comment: I have updated my question, there are some obvious changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `do` function requires that a *function* is passed to it, but by passing `disableTabsByRights(["VIEW"])`, you're passing the return value of the invocation `disableTabsByRights(["VIEW"], undefined)` instead of a function.

Let's pass it an actual function instead, that takes a `type` string and returns a boolean value:

```
do(type => disableTabsByRights(["VIEW"], type))
```

would do the trick.

Otherwise, you could redefine the function as a higher-order function

```
export let disableTabsByRights = 
    (permissions: string[]) => 
    (type: string) => 
        permissions.includes(type);
```

So, now, we can call `disableTabsByRights` with a single parameter (`permissions`), and it will return another function with a single parameter (`type`) which already has a resolved `permissions` value.

To fully call this H-O function, you'd need to `disableTabsByRights(["somePerm"])("someType")`

Now you can use it as you first attempted:

```
do(disableTabsByRights(["VIEW"])); //now disableTabsByRights(["VIEW"]) returns a function.
```

As an aside, you could improve your code by specifying the *exact* shape of the function being passed in:

```
do(fn: (type:string) => boolean) { /*...*/ }
```

to enforce better type-safety.

Comment: How does this trick work? Could you explain please, iterations